# Cant fill superview with view programmatically

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, autolayout

I'll try to make subview's sizes same its superview.

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    subView.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(true)
    let viewsDictionary = ["subView": subView]

    view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|[subView]|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary))
    view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|[subView]|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary))
}
```

[image]
What I do wrong?

=========================

Update!

```
subView.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
        let viewsDictionary = ["subView": subView]

        view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-0.0-[subView]-0.0-|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary))
        view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-0.0-[subView]-0.0-|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary))
    }
```

But no effect =(

Thx a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two mistakes (at least). First:

```
subView.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(true)
```

That needs to be `false`, not `true`.

Second: You don't want to simply do this in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`, because that method will be called many times during the life of your app, and you're going to be adding new constraints unconditionally every time.

Comment: Well, this is why I said "at least". You say "no effect", but how do I know that these variables are even the right variables? For example, is `subView` actually a pointer to this view? Or that its superview is the right superview? I know, though, that code of this sort _will_ work if everything points to the right thing; for example, look at this code, where I create a scroll view in code and give it constraints to overlap its superview exactly: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch07p362scrollViewInCode2/ch20p670scrollViewInCode2/ViewController.swift

Comment: Thx a lot, your code works right, could you answer for another question? I changed your code from "H:|-(10)-[lab]", to "H:|-(0)-[lab]-(0)-|", but labels widths is not  equal sc width, tell me, pls, how it work and what I need to learn to understanding auto layouts, thx a lot again!

Comment: If my answer helped you, please accept it (checkmark). If this leads to a new question, ask a new question; do not use comments to "leech" one question onto another.